# WPF windows client application on windows 8 pro tablet

Tags: c#, windows-8, desktop-application, tablet-pc

currently I am working on a project in which the client GUI application is developed using WPF and C# and it calls a service on the webserver for business related functionalities. This client application is developed for desktop clients.

Now we have a requirement to make the application which was being developed for desktop, to work on a windows tablet (OS windows 8 pro).

So I want to know whether I can Use the MSI generated for desktop application  can be used on Windows 8 pro tablet without any changes or not? Will the application work as its working in desktop?

If not then what all things I need to do for running the application in windows 8 pro tablet

I would be grateful if any one could answer these two questions.

Comment: If the tablet has an x86 or x64 processor, you're good to go. If the tablet is ARM, you'll simply need to rebuild the client application for ARM. It shouldn't require any code changes.

Comment: All .NET Desktop applications can run on the Surface Pro.  This doesn't seem to be a well researched question.

Comment: And what about ARM tablets with WindowsRT (OS) - here you need to have an App from AppStore and can forget your WPF application, huh?

Comment: @Ramhound He didn't say "Surface" Pro, he said Windows 8 Pro; he never specified the exact device.

Comment: @duDE As long as the WPF application is built targeting ARM, it will work on WinRT.

Comment: I don't think so, please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7697427/1758762

Comment: @Murkaeus - A WPF application cannot run on a `Surface RT` or **ANY** `Windows RT` tablet. Only `Windows Store` applications can be ran on the Surface RT and other Windows RT tablets. As for all the other comments `Windows 8 Professional` CANNOT exist on **ANY** pc with an ARM processor. `Windows 8` is `Windows 8` any personal computer running `Windows 8` can run any desktop application that supports that operating system. While `Windows RT` shares the same kernel as `Windows 8` its not considered a direct member of `Windows 8` family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All windows applications (except those compiled only for the ARM architecture - probably a rare thing), will run on a Windows 8 Pro device of any form factor.